# MobX, Is there no way of defining domain stores in the same file as the related components?

Tags: javascript, import, store, inject, mobx

I feel like I'm missing something.

- I can instantiate a store and have it instantiate a chain of components when mounted.
- I can import a store from a file and then reference it in a component.
- I can create a provider and inject it into a component.
- I can use context and pass it that way.

But:

- Why can't I create a store at the top of a file, put all the logic in it, and make all those little stateless components that I want underneath it without having to use a separate file? There isn't any way to reference a store and pass it to the chain in the same file?   Call me old fashioned but I like 'simple, readable, encapsulated, and maintainable'.

Everything I have tried leaves the render() method unable to reference the store.

Thanks in advance for helping launder my ignorance lol.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a lot to benefit from using separated files for stores (or even components), It helps your code become more reusable,
And for my opinion a lot cleaner & readable,
But, I guess that depends on personal opinion & usage.

You can actually write all in one place, you need to define all of your store classes, and create an instance for each one, which you will use in your components.

Here is a sample of how you can do it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

// Define the store(s)
class TestStore {
    @observable arrayTest = ["Item", "Another item"];

    constructor() {
        // More MobX stuff...
    }
}

// Create an instance for each store, to be used in components
let testStore = new TestStore();


// Define the component(s)
@observer
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }


    render() {
        // Using the store instance we defined above
        let { arrayTest } = testStore;

        return <div>
            {arrayTest.map(item => <p>{item}</p>)}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I get it. So we need to make sure that the render method of each component has a local reference to call. That's simple enough.  So, I'll try this with classes that extend the component, and constants, and see what happens.  (Take me a few hours.) ;)

Comment: Yes, that was the answer.  
Lessons
0 - Passing functions down a component hierarchy is unreliable
1 - But we can pass data as props, 
2 - Instantiate component store as variable in-module.
3 - Reference component store in each component
4 - Create local functions to access store methods.
5 - Bind events to local functions.
6 - Local functions access react-dom properties and don't pass parameters so that we don't call functions upon initial render.
7 - Mark hierarch @observ(able/er)

No way with Mobx to get away from classes.
Price we pay for Mobx.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a store that will only be used by the component(s) in one file, you might as well just create a stateful component with some observable data.

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gaxuhufefe/edit?js,output))**

```
@observer
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  @observable count = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => ++this.count, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> Count: {this.count} </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, although the reasons why are application specific.  Thanks.